# SQL CONCAT multiples fields and multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a little problem with my SQL to `concat` 2 query in a same row.

Here's my first request:

```
SELECT lien, id, 
CASE WHEN inactif = 0 THEN 'Oui' ELSE 'Non' END AS 'Actif' 
FROM redirection.elementsOutils 
WHERE lien LIKE '%saaprod/soutien_tache/redirection.asp%'
ORDER BY inactif, dateMAJ
```

Here's the result:

```
lien    id  Actif
http://saaprod/soutien_tache/redirection.asp?id=4466    4467    Oui
```

Here's my second request (I need id from the precedent result):

```
SELECT id, clics AS 'Total clics', clicsAnneeActuelle,
    nbEmployesAnneActuelle, dateMAJ, 
CASE WHEN inactif = 0 THEN 'Oui'ELSE 'Non' END AS 'Actif' 
FROM redirection.elementsParAnnee('2021-01-01 00:00:00.0') 
WHERE id >0  AND (nom LIKE '%4466%'
    OR id LIKE '%4466%' OR lien LIKE '%4466%')
```

Here's the result:

```
id  Total clics clicsAnneeActuelle  nbEmployesAnneActuelle  dateMAJ Actif
4466    284 30  18  2021-09-02  Oui
4467    225 28  16  NULL    Oui
```

Here's what I want:

```
lien    id  Actif Infos
http://saaprod/soutien_tache/redirection.asp?id=4466    4467    Oui  {id:4466,  clcis:284   clicsAnneeActuelle:30,  nbEmpolyesAnneeActuelle:18, dateMAJ:2021-09-02, Actif:Oui}; {id:4467,   clcis:225,  clicsAnneeActuelle:28,  nbEmpolyesAnneeActuelle:16, dateMAJ:NULL,   Actif:Oui}
```

How I can do that?

Comment: can those two tables be joined together? if so provide the join columns and the solution is easy

Comment: @Doug Coats
What you suggest provide two lines, with the first part duplicated. The need is to concatenate the two rows, which your join does not provide.

Answer (score -1):

You should aggregate the data in the second query and only then do the full join:

```html
select * from (
SELECT lien, id, 
CASE WHEN inactif = 0 THEN 'Oui' ELSE 'Non' END AS 'Actif' 
FROM redirection.elementsOutils 
WHERE lien LIKE '%saaprod/soutien_tache/redirection.asp%'
ORDER BY inactif, dateMAJ
)as a ,
(
SELECT '{'||STRING_AGG('id:'||id||', clics:'||clics||',clicsAnneeActuelle:'||clicsAnneeActuelle||', nbEmployesAnneActuelle:'||nbEmployesAnneActuelle||', dateMAJ:'||dateMAJ||'Actif:'||
CASE WHEN inactif = 0 THEN 'Oui'ELSE 'Non' END,'}; {')||'}' as Infos
FROM redirection.elementsParAnnee('2021-01-01 00:00:00.0') 
WHERE id >0  AND (nom LIKE '%4466%' OR id LIKE '%4466%' OR lien LIKE '%4466%') 
) as b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortunately, I have SQL Server 2016.

Comment: this solution is awful if it ever needed to be set based, as youd get cartesian products of all the results

Comment: STRING_AGG type of function is the only way to produce the result you want, otherwise, you should write UDF that simulates this STRING_AGG operation.